# app.blade.php layout not seeing updated user info

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm building a site using Laravel 5.2.  I have a function that simply changes one attribute of a user.  It changes the "type" attribute from "individual" to "business". The function is simple and changes the database.  It looks like this:

```
public function addBusiness() {
    $user = Auth::user()->update([
        'type' => 'business'
    ]);

    Session::flash('msg_title', 'Awesome!');
    Session::flash('message', 'You\'ve added a business to your account');
    return redirect()->back(); 

}
```

If I display the attribute in the body it displays business as it should.

However, in the header (located in the layout app.blade.php file) it still shows "individual." I did a test where I had `{{Auth::user()->type}}` in both app.blade.php and my body blade file, it displayed "individual" in app.blade.php, and "business" in the body on the same screen.

It even persists after `Session::flush();` after logout/login, or even login from another browser.

Answer (score 0):

try \Auth::setUser($user) after updating user

check def in laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard::setUser

Comment: That didn't work.  The function is actually updating the correct user.  When checking the database the value does get updated.  The app just seems to be remembering the old value somehow, but only the header (app.blade.php) not the file. very strange.

Comment: ... sigh... had @if(Auth::user()='individual') above that's = instead of == fixed. thanks for your help.